# Proof of infinite solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this none linear ODE of the form: $x' = -3x^{4/3} \sin t$, I am supposed to show that this ODE has infinitely many solutions and to find maximal interval of existence of the solution that satisfies x(a) = 0 , I have solved this problem by the variable separable method, i was thinking to use the constant of integration to show that this function would have more than 1 solution for different initial values and then conclude that it has an infinitely many solutions. But i have a strange feeling that this is not sufficient. And for the condition x(a) = 0, i observed there is no solution at this point because i am having 0 = 1.....

Can i get a kind hint from anyone on how i can be off the hook or sure of my process...

Comment: There **is** a solution, $x$ identically $0$.

Comment: But how do i verify this.. I mean at x(a)=0 my solution becomes 0=1, i just saw a text that says this is the only solution from -ve infinity to +ve infinity.. Please kindly give a lil explanation on this

Comment: If $x$ is identically $0$ then the right-hand side is $0$, as is the left-hand side.

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much i made some readings on the zero solution and found it was correct.. Called the Equilibrium Solution... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(Unclear what your equation is; can you please typeset it in LaTeX? I take it that $4/3$ is the exponent of $x$ and $\sin(t)$ multiplied everything. Please confirm.)

Your hint is: center manifold. If that doesn't tell you anything, note that the ODE has a nontrivial solution (you found it when you separated variables) & a trivial solution (André Nicolas above gave it). You can glue the two together to make (for example) a solution which equals the nontrivial one in an interval (or ray) & is zero outside it. The interval/ray can be chosen arbitrarily, & each choice gives another solution. This shouldn't be too hard putting in math.

**EDIT** Please consult Al Kelley's '*The stable, center-stable, center, center-unstable, unstable manifolds*' J Diff Eqs **3(4)** 546-570 (1967). Section 4 with the associated figure should give you a good idea about how to go glueing together solutions.

Comment: Yes confirmed, thats what the equation is... Please i didnt get the descriptions well. Anyway to breakdown further please

Comment: Edit your post first. Also, add the nontrivial solution you found. This will be a collaborative effort :).

Comment: I have edited it but i find a problem putting Latex statement on this forum.. Please i would be glad if u can also give me a recommended reading where i can get maybe 1 or two of such problems and their solutions so i can study it and apply to mine... I have read existence and uniqueness chapters in over 5 textbooks on nonlinear ODE between yesterday and today, but most only give theorem and no application.. Thanks

Comment: @IbrahimSarumi - see edit above.